How to use AutoHotkey to make mouse wheel click reliably open the "Open with" Windows File Explorer context menu?
I frequently use a multitude of programs to open the same file. For example, I often open .txt and .py files with Notepad, Notepad++, and Visual Studio Code. Another example is that I like opening PDF files for quick reading with Google Chrome, but for more extensive use, I have to open it in Adobe Acrobat Pro.
All of these times, I have to manually select the file (click #1), right click (click #2), physically move the mouse cursor to the exact position where it says "Open with", click on "Open with" (click #3), and finally select the program of my choice (click #4).
Doing this many times becomes annoying, so I always wanted Windows to just have a built-in feature that allows the user to map a mouse wheel click to automatically open up the "Open with" context menu. This would reduce the number of clicks to at most three (select item, mouse wheel click, click on program of choice), but more importantly, it would remove the necessity of having to physically move the cursor to the exact location of the "Open with" option, which is arguably the most annoying part.
I thought that there must be some robust way to accomplish this with AutoHotkey. I've never used AutoHotkey before, so its use is new to me. I put together an initial script that almost gets the job done:
#SingleInstance Force  ; Ensures only one instance runs
SendMode "Input"

; Hook into the middle mouse click
~MButton::
{
    ; Check if the active window is File Explorer
    activeClass := WinGetClass("A")
    if (activeClass = "CabinetWClass" or activeClass = "ExplorerWClass")
    {
        ; First check if any file is selcted. If not, exit immediately.
        explorerHwnd := WinGetID("A")
        if(!Explorer_GetSelected(explorerHwnd)){
            return
        }

        ; Only get the control name since that's all we're using
        MouseGetPos , , , &control

        ; Check if we're actually on an item in File Explorer
        if (InStr(control, "DirectUIHWND") or InStr(control, "SysListView32")) {
            ; Simulate a right-click at the current position
            Click "Right"

            ; Wait a moment for the context menu to appear
            Sleep 100

            ; Try opening with `h`
            hClicked := TryOpenWith("h")
            if(hClicked){
                return
            }
            else{
                Sleep 100
                TryOpenWith("w")
                return
            }
        }
    }
    return
}
TryOpenWith(mnemonic := "h"){
    ; Get the current active window to compare later
    origWin := WinGetID("A")

    Send mnemonic
    Sleep 100

    ; Wait briefly to check if a new window or menu appears
    Loop 10 {
        Sleep 50
        newWin := WinGetID("A")
        if (newWin != origWin) {
            return true  ; A new window (likely the submenu) appeared
        }
    }

    ; If no change in the active window, assume failure
    return false
}
; Helper function to check if files are selected in Explorer
Explorer_GetSelected(hwnd := 0) {
    if (!hwnd){
        hwnd := WinGetID("A")
    }

    for window in ComObject("Shell.Application").Windows {
        if (window.HWND != hwnd){
            continue
        }

        selection := window.Document.SelectedItems
        if (selection.Count > 0) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

BUT there are several edge cases that break the script. In my manual testing, I noticed that—after the user has already selected the item and right-clicked on the item—the "Open with" context menu can mostly be directly opened by hitting the h key once. But for some files, I need to actually use the w key, and other times, I actually have to hit the h key twice and then hit the Enter key (these scenarios occur when more than one menu option is associated with the h key).
The ideal script would automatically detect which mnemonic key to hit (and how many times, along with any other key combinations) to directly open up the "Open with" context menu. But I can't seem to do that. Is there any simple, robust way that allows me to map the mouse wheel click to directly open up the "Open with" context menu, for files in File Explorer?
For context, I'm on Windows 10 version 22H2, using AutoHotkey version 2.0.18.
